# Error en definición de función que tiene una tupla como argumento

Tags: python, jupyter

Tengo un problema con este código y no se como solucionarlo, lo vi en un video en el que lo ejecutaba en jupyter notebook y le daba el resultado:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np
from scipy.integrate import odeint



k = 4.0    
m = 1.0
B = -1

def harmonic((x,y),t):
    return [y,-k*x/m + B*y/m]

inicial = [0.7,0.5]
t_output = np.arange(0,15,0.01)
result = odeint(harmonic,inicial,t_output)

fig, ax2 = plt.subplots(ncols=1, figsize=(10,10))
xx, yy = result.T
plt.plot(t_output,xx)
plt.plot(t_output,yy)
plt.show()
```

Yo lo pruebo también en jupyter notebook pero me da el siguiente  error de sintaxis:

> ```
> File "<ipython-input-15-761622132ca8>", line 9
>
>     def harmonic((x,y),t):
>
>                  ^
>
> SyntaxError: invalid syntax
> ```

---

La idea es ver, a través de un gráfico, el movimiento oscilatorio que genera una masa sujetada por un resorte, utilizando ecuaciones diferenciales de segundo orden.

El video fue subido en 2015, no se si habrá cambiado la sintaxis o a qué se debe el error.

Comment: Hola Leo, bienvenido a [es.so]. Por favor, lee el [tour] para aprender el funcionamiento básico del sitio. Dices que no sabes si hubo cambio de sintaxis... has mirado la documentacion para ver qué se espera de ese metodo ?  Que has intentado para resolver el problema?  MIira [ask] y [mcve] para más info. Un saludo.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Estás usando Python 3 y el código es para Python 2.

El error concreto está en:

```
def harmonic((x, y), t)
```

y es causado por `(x, y)`, el uso de tuplas como parámetro en la definición de funciones se eliminó en Python 3, como se especifica en [PEP 3113](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-3113/).

Tienes varias opciones, por ejemplo:

```
def harmonic(v, t):
    x, y = v
    return [y,-k*x/m + B*y/m]
```

Con esto tu código es perfectamente válido para Python 3. La función recibe la tupla con los valores `x` e `y` en el parámetro `v` y con `x, y = v` se desempaquetan de forma explícita.